# for loop in xslt page

Tags: xslt

I get from my xml some integer and I want to get all numbers between 1 and the gotten number .

I want to insert those numbers as a columns names .

Is it possible to do ?

Thanks .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
 <xsl:sequence select="1 to $N"/>
```

---

**II. XSLT 1.0 DVC solution**

The answer by @nd (using primitive recursion) is a good one.

**However, if a sequence of numbers is to be generated with sufficiently big length (1000 or more) primitive recursion typically ends abnormally with stack overflow** due to too-deep recursion.

**The DVC (Divide and Conquer) method can be used to avoid call stack overflow for any practical case**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output method="text"/>

     <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:call-template name="displayNumbers">
        <xsl:with-param name="pStart" select="1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pEnd" select="1000000"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template name="displayNumbers">
      <xsl:param name="pStart"/>
      <xsl:param name="pEnd"/>

      <xsl:if test="not($pStart > $pEnd)">
       <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$pStart = $pEnd">
          <xsl:value-of select="$pStart"/>
          <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:variable name="vMid" select=
           "floor(($pStart + $pEnd) div 2)"/>
          <xsl:call-template name="displayNumbers">
           <xsl:with-param name="pStart" select="$pStart"/>
           <xsl:with-param name="pEnd" select="$vMid"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
          <xsl:call-template name="displayNumbers">
           <xsl:with-param name="pStart" select="$vMid+1"/>
           <xsl:with-param name="pEnd" select="$pEnd"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:if>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), it outputs the numbers from one to one million**. The maximum dept of the call stack during this transformation is only 19 (log2(N)).

---

**III. Non-recursive XSLT 1.0 solution**:

**In case the length of the numeric sequence to be generated is not too big** (more precisely , doesn't exceed the number of the available nodes in an XML document (such as the XSLT stylesheet itself)), **then we can use a non-recursive solution, known as the [Piez method](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/muench.html#d9940e300)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDoc" select="document('')"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vNodes" select=
 "$vDoc//node() | $vDoc//@* | $vDoc//namespace::*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:for-each select="$vNodes[not(position() > 40)]">
      <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
     </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied to any XML document (not used) it produces the numbers from 1 to 40**:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
```

Answer (score 1):

A word of advice first: Usually such a question indicates that things should be done differently, in a more XSLT-esque way - e.g. by a template matching a source XML tree and using `position()` to get the index of the current node.

But if you need to, you can get all integer numbers between 1 and an arbitrary number. However, as you cannot reassign variables in XSLT, the standard way to do that is to use recursion:

```
<xsl:template name="counter">
  <xsl:param name="current"/>
  <xsl:param name="max"/>
  <xsl:if test=" $max >= $current">
    <!-- do whatever you want to do with the current item here -->
    <th><xsl:value-of select="$current"/></th>

    <!-- increase the counter for the recursive call -->
    <xsl:call-template name="counter">
      <xsl:with-param name="current" select="$current + 1"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="max" select="$max"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, call the recursive template with a start value and your maximum number:

```
<xsl:call-template name="counter">
  <xsl:with-param name="current" select="1"/>
  <xsl:with-param name="max" select="$gotten-number"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```