# use xslt to insert a number n times to a xml document

Tags: xml, loops, xslt, foreach

I'd like to repeatedly add a elect to and xml structure, the number of times depends on a value attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="zahlen.xsl" type="text/xsl"?> 
<numbers>
    <number value="8"/>
    <number value="3"/>
    <number value="13"/>
    <number value="2"/>
    <number value="9"/>
</numbers>
```

I have this XSLT that returns each number one time

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
                
 <xsl:for-each select="numbers/number">

       <p> <xsl:value-of select="@value"/></p>
   
 </xsl:for-each>

                    </xsl:template>

                    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

what I want is something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<p>8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8</p>
<p>3 3 3</p>
<p>13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13</p>
<p>2 2</p>
<p>9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9</p>
```

I tried to look for [loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47198814/using-xslt-to-transform-xml-entries-a-specified-number-of-times-each) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076323/xslt-looping-from-1-to-60) for xslt, but I can't reproduce them.

Comment: Are you limited to XSLT 1.0? Which XSLT engine are you using?

Comment: I am not limeted to XSLT 1. it is a learning question, no concrete engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution in XSLT 1.0 that uses a recursive template.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <output>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="numbers/number"/>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="number">
        <p>
            <xsl:call-template name="iteration">
                <xsl:with-param name="number" select="@value"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="iter" select="@value"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="iteration">
        <xsl:param name="number"/>
        <xsl:param name="iter"/>
        <xsl:if test="$iter>0">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($number,' ')"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="iteration">
                <xsl:with-param name="number" select="$number"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="iter" select="$iter - 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
        
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1SDkS